# Looking for the German-to-English equivalent of Beaton's "A Practical Dictionary of German Usage"

Tags: resource

The articles in K. B. Beaton's *A Practical Dictionary of German Usage* [PDGU] are devoted to individual English keywords, and give extended, detailed descriptions of possible ways to translate these English keywords into German, paying attention to details such as connotation, nuance, register, geographical prevalence, etc.  Naturally enough, these articles are arranged alphabetically according to their English keywords.

I'm looking for the German-to-English equivalent of this: namely, a compendium of equally detailed descriptions of possible translations of German keywords into English.  Importantly, I'm looking for a work addressed to speakers of English.

---

<sup>Note that, despite the word "dictionary" in its name, PDGU is not really a conventional English-German dictionary.  It covers relatively few English terms, compared to a medium-sized English-German dictionary.  On the other hand, for those terms it does cover, it gives a lot more information than one would find in a typical English-German dictionary.</sup>

<sup>Also, I should point out that the last several pages of PDGU consist of cross-references of German terms to the pages where they are mentioned in the work's main section.  Thus one *could*, in principle, use these cross-references to approximate the German-English reference I'm looking for.  This, however, is not only laborious, since the German words are often mentioned in several disparate articles, but also ultimately unsatisfactory, because it only provides disconnected facets of the German word, rather than full, well-rounded picture of it.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Almost a month without answers now, so I dare posting an answer that's more of a stab in the dark.

Sadly, I can't tell if it is a proper equivalent since I don't know PDGU. So take this with a grain of salt and check it out before you buy.

[https://www.amazon.de/Langenscheidt-Praktisches-Wörterbuch-Englisch-Langenscheidt-Redaktion/dp/3468104510#customerReviews](https://www.amazon.de/Langenscheidt-Praktisches-W%C3%B6rterbuch-Englisch-Langenscheidt-Redaktion/dp/3468104510#customerReviews)

According to amazon reviews and descriptions, it could fit the bill.

Oh, and don't buy from Amazon.

Comment: The interesting link refers to the 2007 edition. Unfortunately the newer from 2013 has only half the number of pages and so may be something completely different.